# Static Enum in Rust

Tags: enums, rust, static

Is it possible define an enum without worrying about memory allocation in Rust?

Suppose the following is the definition of my enum.

```rust
pub enum Orientation {
    North,
    South,
    East,
    West,
}
```

I would like to know whether it is possible to refer to the same instance of say `Orientation::North` in the code.

Does the following code produce two separate instances of `North`?

```
let o1 = Orientation::North;
let o2 = Orientation::North;
```

I know I can achieve it by defining static variables like below. 
Is there a better (syntactically safer/simpler/cleaner) way to do the same thing?

```
pub enum Orientation {
    North,
    South,
    East,
    West,
}

static NORTH: Orientation = Orientation::North;
static SOUTH: Orientation = Orientation::South;
static WEST: Orientation = Orientation::West;
static EAST: Orientation = Orientation::East;
```

Comment: Each variant will be encoded as a single byte. There's nothing stored anywhere at runtime, and the compiled code will look exactly as if you were just comparing numeric bytes. Storing the `enum` variants as static variables will achieve nothing, as referencing them will mean passing around pointers - which are 8 bytes!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code you are asking about, at runtime, is identical to as if you had written:

```
let o1: u8 = 0;
let o2: u8 = 0;
```

Enums give you abstraction over what is really happening so you get efficiency and syntactic convenience at the same time, along with type-checking and errors when you forget a variant in a match.

Creating static "constants" won't achieve anything, because passing bytes around is about the fastest thing you could do already.

> Is there a better (syntactically safer/simpler/cleaner) way to do the same thing?

The "best" way to use the enum is in exactly the simplest way possible:

```
let o1 = Orientation::North;
let o2 = Orientation::North;
```

Comment: The reason I was confused with Rust enum is that it lets wrap an element like `enum WebEvent { KeyPress(char),}`. I assume Rust treats this case differently?

Comment: @JamesParker not really, it's just that when there's associated data the enum grows such that it's big enough to encompass the associated data *and* the discriminant, otherwise you just have the discriminant (which is generally an u8 unless you use a custom repr). Basically the "base case" is as if the associated data was unit (the empty tuple, `()`), which is zero-sized, and thus the only space necessary for each variant is the discriminant.